# Entity Framework 6.0 and Error with mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to map following class on two tables -

```
public class Centre
{
    public string CentreID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Order { get; set;}
    public string InfoText { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping used is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Centre>()
    .Map(m =>
            {
                m.Properties(t => new { t.CentreID, t.Name, t.Order });
                m.ToTable("Centres");
            })
.Map(m =>
        {
            m.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("InfoText");
            m.ToTable("CentreContents");
            m.Requires("Attribute").HasValue("Description");
        })
.Map(m =>
        {
            //m.Properties(t => new { t.InfoText });
            m.Property(t => t.InfoText);
            m.ToTable("CentreContents");
            m.Requires("Attribute").HasValue("Intro");
        });
```

The first 2 map works as expected. Adding 3rd map gives error. What expected is , there is a one to many relation and each record from linked table needs to be mapped on a property. The database is already existing in the application and not possible to change the structure. With view it is possible but don't want to create view for same.

Comment: removed the semicolon. It was a typo mistake in question. The error is 'mapping to same table is multiple times' and raised at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semi colon in this part of your statement...

```
                });
        .Map(m =>
```

Oh and detailing the error can be pretty helpful.